# How to use query sql for show parent table in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, parent

How to display room rates using mysql query?

I have 2 tables, namely the room table and the rental rate table, I want to display the rental rates for each room.

[table room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90AYx.png)

[table rental rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFqCl.png)

How to call it with mysql query ? i have tried using grouping, join. But it didn't work. Please help

Comment: You can use eloquent ORM or DB facade for getting data from database instead of using sql queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Room model add this relationship:

```
    public function rates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RentalRate::class);
    }
```

In Controller call:

```
$rooms = Room::with('rates')->get();
```

Read more about [Laravel Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)